# How can we implement CSP- Content Security Policy in Reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, asp.net-core-3.1, content-security-policy

I want to add csp as meta tag in my html page in React application.

1. I've created ASP.NET Core with ReactJS Project.
2. Inside Client App folder structure it used create-react-app demo.
3. and then I added this meta tag in index.html

This is the meta tag code; but while using this code i'm getting error.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; ">
```

Below is the error message:

```
styleTagTransform.js:12 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-aw/cuq+oNW2VmZeRKB38rTQ+6lr2Wol35x/gNAPQqbk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

React adding style as inline

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <html lang="en"><head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; ">
      <script defer="" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><style>/*!
    <style>.css1{color:red'}</style>
  <style>.css2{color:red'}</style>
        <title>Project2</title>
        <noscript>
          You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
        </noscript>
        <div id="root"><div><header><nav class="navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm ng-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 navbar navbar-light"><div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Project2</a><button aria-label="Toggle navigation" type="button" class="mr-2 navbar-toggler"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button><div class="d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse collapse navbar-collapse"><ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow"><li class="nav-item"><a class="text-dark nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="text-dark nav-link" href="/counter">Counter</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="text-dark nav-link" href="/fetch-data">Fetch data</a></li></ul></div></div></nav></header><div class="container"><div><h1>Hello, world!</h1><p>Welcome to your new single-page application, built with:</p><ul><li><a href="https://get.asp.net/">ASP.NET Core</a> and <a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx">C#</a> for cross-platform server-side code</li><li><a href="https://facebook.github.io/react/">React</a> for client-side code</li><li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a> for layout and styling</li></ul><p>To help you get started, we have also set up:</p><ul><li><strong>Client-side navigation</strong>. For example, click <em>Counter</em> then <em>Back</em> to return here.</li><li><strong>Development server integration</strong>. In development mode, the development server from <code>create-react-app</code> runs in the background automatically, so your client-side resources are dynamically built on demand and the page refreshes when you modify any file.</li><li><strong>Efficient production builds</strong>. In production mode, development-time features are disabled, and your <code>dotnet publish</code> configuration produces minified, efficiently bundled JavaScript files.</li></ul><p>The <code>ClientApp</code> subdirectory is a standard React application based on the <code>create-react-app</code> template. If you open a command prompt in that directory, you can run <code>npm</code> commands such as <code>npm test</code> or <code>npm install</code>.</p></div></div></div></div>

        <!--
          This HTML file is a template.
          If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
          You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
          The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
          To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
          To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
        -->
      
    </body></html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Also added this piece of code in package.json but didn't work.

1. SET INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=true
2. SET INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false

note: css code was big so removed and added normal syntax

```
<style>.css1{color:red'}</style>
```

.css2{color:red'}

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the provided input, it seems that the problem could be that the js file styleTagTransform.js adds inline js. You will likely need to rewrite or replace this file to change the behavior if you don't want to allow 'unsafe-inline' for scripts. It could possibly work to add the hash of that style if it doesn't change, but you should check that solution in different browsers.

The other inline style tags like

```
    <style>.css1{color:red'}</style>
  <style>.css2{color:red'}</style>
```

should either move to a .css file, or you can try to gather all the inline style into one or a few tags and then allow the hash of each, which the browser will tell you.

Comment: I'm using "create-react-app". By default it is creating this inline CSS. I'm having hard time to move all this Style tag CSS to one .css file. Can you help with this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't.